# Get ID of the element that was Bootstrap popover-ed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have the following Javascript code that represents an string of html elements:

```
html = '<tr>' +
'<td class="editMap" data-mode="option" data-wsid="'+row.option_id+
'" data-map="'+row.mapping_id+'" id="option-'+row.option_id+'">'+
'<span title="Options Mapping" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left"style="cursor:pointer;">'+value+
'</span></td>'+'</tr>';
```

the html variable is actually inside a loop. I have as well the popover code that displays the details of a particular div

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  html: true, 
  container: body,

  content: function() {
    return $('#popover-content').html();
  }
});

<div id="popover-content" class="row" style="display:none;">
  <input  class="btn btn-xs btn-info" type="submit" value="Yes" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"/>
  <input  class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" type="submit" value="No" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"/>
</div>
```

What I want is to actually get the id of the element that was popovered, which is in this case represented by **"option-'+row.option_id+'"**. I have tried the following but it seems to not be working:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').each( function() {
  $(this).popover({ 
    html : true,
    content: this.id,
    console.log(this.id);
  });
});
```

Please help me get the id. It might be an elementary level question but I'm new to Javascript

Comment: try `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: `this` is a reference to `dom element` where `$(this)` is a jquery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access current element using `$(this)` instead of only `this`.

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').each( function() {
      //try doing console log out of popover.
      console.log($(this).attr('id'));
      $(this).popover({ 
                        html : true,
                        content: $(this).attr('id')
                     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$()` is the jQuery constructor function.

`this` is a reference to the DOM element of invocation.

In `$(this)`, you are just passing the `this` in `$()` as a parameter so that you could call jQuery methods and functions.

So, your code will look like :

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').each( function() {
    $(this).popover({ 
        html : true,
        content: $(this).attr('id'),
        console.log(this.id);
    });
});
```